# Change css after rotateY

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I looking for changing my background-color after a css rotateY when my div is hover

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {  
 0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0% 5;
 }  
 100%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0% 5;
 }  

}
.hex:hover{
  background:red;
   -webkit-animation-name: spin; 
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
}
```

Comment: you mean the page background or just the element with the .hex class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define that in you keyframe as your element is animating on hover so you can change the background color in the animation keyframe itself.
Try this:

```
 @-webkit-keyframes spin {  
 0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0% 5;
 }  
 100%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0% 5;
       background:red;
 }  

}
.hex:hover{

   -webkit-animation-name: spin; 
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
}
.hexHovered {
          background:red;
          }
```

To retain the backgroud color at hover you can use this javascript code.

```
$(".hex").hover(
function () { $(this).addClass(".hexHovered")
});​
```

Comment: Yes the animation would only be fired at hover and all the changes too. What do you want to do ?

Comment: With your code, the changes doesn't stay on hover, changes are well done at 100% but when animation is done, the changes disappear

Comment: Your animation would only stay up to time you have mentioned in the code. If you want to change the Div color after hover then sorry but I don't think there's a way to achieve this with CSS. I am editing the answer and posting the javascript solution. Hope that might help.

Comment: @RajeshDhiman You can make the change of an animation persistent with CSS. the property to get this is animation-fill-mode. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the animation "persist" in time using animation-fill-mode.
Asuming that you want the color to persist, but not the rotation, it is alittle bit more complicated; you need two animations so that you can make only one persistent.

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {  
 0% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);  }  
 100%{ -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);  }  
}
@-webkit-keyframes red {  
 0%   { background: white; }  
 100% { background: red; } 
}

.hex {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:  none, forwards;
   -webkit-animation-name: spin, red; 
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 0; 
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s, 0.1s; 
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0s 1s;         
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0% 5;
}
.hex:hover{
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVxRc/)